# Deciding how much memory to dynamically allocate based on user input

Tags: c, string, pointers

I need to write a program that does the following:

- Prompt the user and ask them how many words they wish to enter
- Allocate dynamic memory using malloc() to store each individual word
- Dynamically allocate another array to store pointers to each of these individual word strings, fill it with the pointers
- Dynamically allocate an additional array for temporary storage of an incoming word
- Prompt the user to enter a string with the same number of words they previously entered.
- Read the users' input into the temporary array one word at a time, once each word has been read, transfer it into one of the dynamically allocated arrays.
- After all of this I should be able to print each word individually.

A sample run could look like this:

```
How many words do you wish to enter? 5 
Enter 5 words now:
I enjoyed doing this exercise
Here are your words:
I 
enjoyed 
doing 
this 
exercise
```

When reading the string, the program should read the word into a temporary array of char, use malloc() to allocate enough storage to hold the word, and store the address in the array of char pointers.How to handle this step?

Here is my question: How can I size my temporary array to be large enough to hold any arbitrary word the user may enter, and then how do I transfer it to the storage array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
enum { MAX_WORD_SIZE = sizeof("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious") };
void resign(char**,int);
int main()
{
    char **p;
    int n,i;
    printf("How many words do you wish to enter?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    puts("Here are your words:");
    resign(p,n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        puts(p[i]);
    }
}
 void resign(char**p,int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    char c;
    char * temp_word = NULL;
    getchar();
    temp_word = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE);
        while ((c=getchar())!='\n') {
        if (c!=' ') temp_word[i++]=c;
        else {temp_word[i]='\0';
        p[j]=temp_word;
        temp_word = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE);
            i=0;j++;}
}
    temp_word[i]='\0';
    p[j]=temp_word;
    free(temp_word);
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What parts of your code do you have problems with?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're not going to get help posting a problem and saying you don't know what to do. You need to show you've made some effort to try and solve this.

Comment: When reading the string, the program should read the word into a temporary array of char, use malloc() to allocate enough storage to hold the word, and store the address in the array of char pointers.How to handle this step?

Comment: @PeterMiehle I hate to scold, but ["As long as the question is in salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved like any other post."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: @usb-pineapple I am revising your question based on what I think you're trying to ask.

Comment: @usb-pineapple Once my edit goes through, post a comment to let me know if that captures the spirit of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Nick you put much too much afford into a "make my homework for me"-question!

Comment: @PeterMiehle I felt like there was a good question  inside that post waiting to come out. Specifically "how do I estimate how big to size a buffer to handle arbitrary user input strings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a description of [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

It takes a parameter `size`, in bytes.

So if the user entered 5 words, then you need to first allocate an array big enough to store 5 pointers.

Eg.

```
char ** words = NULL;
words = malloc(sizeof(char *) * <NUMBER OF CHARACTERS THE USER ENTERED>);
```

If we assume ASCII is being used and a character is a char, then each letter in each of the words is a byte. We also need to account for any spaces, line feeds, perhaps a carriage return, and a trailing null.

So how many letters are in a word? IDK, that's up to you. But if we assume that ["Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" from Mary Poppins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRFHXMQP-QU) in the longest word we will encounter, then we need to allocate at least 34 characters, plus an extra for a trailing null terminator. So that leaves us with up to 35 bytes per word.

This will work:

```
enum { MAX_WORD_SIZE = sizeof("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious") };
```

This will also take into account the trailing `\0` - MAX_WORD_SIZE will be 35.

```
char * temp_word = NULL;
temp_word = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE);
```

To create all of your other word arrays you'd need to do something similar in a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i< <NUMBER OF WORDS THE USER ENTERED>; i++)
{
    words[i] = malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE);
}
```

To convert the number of words entered by the user into an integer you should use [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi)

After this you could use [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) to pull the string from stdin one character at a time and manually place them into temporary you allocated, stopping when you get to a `' '` space.

To copy the temporary array into one of your word arrays you can use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/?kw=strcpy), just ensure your temporary array always has a trailig `\0` after the word.

Don't forget to `free()` that pointer when you're done.

I am assuming you are doing this for some sort of a homework assignment on dynamic memory and that is why your application is defined the way it is. But if you aren't you should consider just reading the input into one buffer first using `fgets()` and using `strtok()` to split the string after its been read. That approach will take more memory but it would be cleaner.

Another thing you should consider doing is using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to do your allocation, that way you can ensure that all of your arrays are initialized with 0's - it could save you from some confusion later on if there is garbage data already in those arrays.

Yet another thing to think about: The temporary array in this example can be allocated automatically or statically using `temp_word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];` since I used an enum to store MAX_WORD_SIZE as a constant. There is no direct need to use malloc for this.